# Base member initialization section C#?

Tags: c#, object, initialization, initialization-list

Does a base member initialization section exist in C#? I tried searching and searching but kept coming up with questions regarding initializing the [List class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). The initialization list I am referring to looks like the example located [here.](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/)

One reason for doing this is to initialize a constant in a class. I'm essentially trying to figure out if I can do the following:

```
public class A{
    private const string _name;
    public A(string name): _name(name){
         //stuff
    }
}
```

Again, I'm trying to do this in C#, not C++. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, C# does not support member initialization before constructor body the same way as C++ does. You can either initialize fields when they are declared or using normal assignament inside contructor body.

The only 2 methods can be used at that position - call to contructor of base class and call to another contructor in the same class. You can check C# specification (i.e. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf, section 17.10 Instance constructors) for details:

```
constructor-declaration:
    attributesopt constructor-modifiersopt constructor-declarator constructor-body

constructor-declarator:
   identifier ( formal-parameter-listopt ) constructor-initializer
constructor-initializer:
  : base ( argument-listopt )
  : this ( argument-listopt )
```

Answer (score 4):

You do this using private readonly fields initialised in the constructor, thus:

```
public class A 
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public A (string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

A `readonly` field can only be initialised inline or in the constructor, and is thereafter constant.

Comment: Just to add to this, `const` has to be defined at compile time. `readonly` works like const, but it HAS to be filled in the constructor, and then can't be changed after (effectively a constant).

Comment: +1. Good point in usung `readonly` (which is likely what OP wants).

Comment: Does this apply to properties as well or only fields? Also, if you don't use an initialization list like in C++, won't you effectively be calling two functions? Like if instead of a string we had a Foo, so you'd be calling the default foo constructor, and then the assignment operator making it somewhat inneficient?

Comment: @thed0ctor, there will be no call to constructor of `Foo` - it will be initialized to null (for `class`)/default value (for `struct`) at object allocation. So calling constructor will not be an extra overhead.

Comment: Thank you. I just found this out after reading [the differences between classes and structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(v=vs.71).aspx). Didn't even know c# had structs. Thanks for the input.